# Asp:Net Required field turn control back color red for validation groups

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have successfully been able to turn the back colour of controls red if validation if a required field triggered. However I can't get it work for controls in groups.

I have this js in each of my pages just before the closing body tag

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
 if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() ==false) {
  for (var i in Page_Validators) {
    try {
        var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
        if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
            control.className = "ErrorControl";

        } else {
            control.className = "";
        }
    } catch (e) {
        var r = 0;
    }
}
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

the following css class for the Error styling.

```
.ErrorControl
{
    background-color: #FBE3E4;
    border: solid 1px Red;
}
```

Here is an example of a control in a validation group

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="vldTelephoneNumber" ControlToValidate="txtTelephoneNumber" ValidationGroup="ResellerGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is the javascript function I use to change the border and background color of the element that is being validated or is deemed invalid when the submit button is clicked. It will only turn the element red of the specific validation group, not all the elements that have a validator.

It also turn the colors back to normal when the validaton has succeeded and the focus is lost.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (typeof (Page_Validators) !== 'undefined') {
            //check the elements at a regular interval to change the color back to normal
            setInterval(function () { fieldValidators() }, 100);
        }
    });

    function fieldValidators() {
        if (typeof (Page_Validators) !== 'undefined') {
            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                var val = Page_Validators[i];
                var ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
                if (ctrl != null && ctrl.style != null) {
                    if (!val.isvalid) {
                        $(ctrl).addClass("ErrorControl");
                    } else if ($(ctrl).hasClass("ErrorControl")) {
                        $(ctrl).removeClass("ErrorControl");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this. How can I call this on page submit. At the moment it works fine when leaving a required field that needs completing.

Comment: also is there a way to do this for dropdowns thanks again

Comment: No need, it will work for every element validated on the page (including dropdowns). Just paste it in the HTML and you'll see. If the element is valid it will get back it's normal color by removing the `ErrorControl` class when focus is lost.

Comment: thanks but it only seems to work for some of elements. Also when I click on  my next button the page calls my code behind but doesnt cause validation even through i have asked it too

Comment: That's a different problem. Then you have a javascript/jQuery error probably. Check your console if that's the case.